# Android Marshmallow requesting for permission runtime in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 device that I'm trying to access the wifi information with. I'm trying to request permission in runtime from a fragment, but the popup does not display.

Here's the code for what I'm trying to do

```
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 1001;
private void requestPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                                            Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE},
                                            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );
        }
    }
```

Can you not request for permissions in a fragment? Must this be done in an activity?

Answer (score 1):

`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` and `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` are not dangerous permission and don't need to be requested at runtime. You need to actually request the `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`.

Note that Support v4 Fragments contain the [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)) method which is the only way you'll get a callback to your Fragment's [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) (using the `ActivityCompat` method will only send the permission result to the Activity).

```
requestPermissions(
    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can request permission from inside fragment try

```
requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

Try below code if you want to handle user selection from inside fragment

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(permissions,PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```